# Why is get () used in this viewBinding example?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I want to know why "private val binding get() = _binding!!" was used here?

```
 private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you got that code from [this page in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments).

Their objective is to give you a way to access the `_binding` value without needing to deal with the fact that `_binding` can be `null`. In the portion of their example that you did not include, they have a comment on `binding` that points out that it can only be used between `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()`. *If* you are in a part of your code where you can *guarantee* that your code will execute between those two callbacks, you can reference `binding`, which will return the value of `_binding` coerced into a not-`null` type (`ResultProfileBinding` instead of `ResultProfileBinding?`).

However, if you get it wrong, and you try referencing `binding` before `onCreateView()` or after `onDestroyView()`, you will crash with a `NullPointerException`.

Personally, I would avoid this approach.